# Making multiple figures in matplotlib with legend on each one

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to make multiple figures in parallel, each with its own legend. My code produces multiple figures but I can only ever get the legend to appear on the last figure instance - is there a way of getting it to appear on all figures? I have a large number of datasets so I would like to be able to use a for loop (or similar) - making each figure separately is not really an option.

I have included a minimum working example below that reproduces the problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X1 = np.linspace(0,5,5)
X2 = np.linspace(1,6,5)
Y1 = np.power(X1,2)
Y2 = np.power(X2,2)
Z1 = np.power(X1,3)
Z2 = np.power(X2,3)

Xs = [X1,X2]
Ys = [Y1,Y2]
Zs = [Z1,Z2]

# Marker size
size = 100

for x,y,z, in zip(Xs,Ys,Zs):
    plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.scatter(x,y,linewidth=1.5,s=size,facecolors='#0571b0',marker='o',alpha=0.5,label='A label')
    ax.scatter(x,z,linewidth=1.5,s=size,facecolors='#92c5de',marker='o',alpha=0.5,label='Another label')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.45,1.), loc='top left',scatterpoints=1,fontsize=8)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the legend is simply out of the figure. You place it at `(1.45, 1)` (in axes coordinates. Putting it at (1,1) and setting the location e.g. to `loc="upper right"` (note that "top left" does not exist), will produce the legend in the plot.

Here is the complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X1 = np.linspace(0,5,5)
X2 = np.linspace(1,6,5)
Xs = [X1,X2]
Ys = [X1**2,X2**2]
Zs = [X1**3,X2**3]

# Marker size
size = 100

for x,y,z, in zip(Xs,Ys,Zs):
    plt.figure()
    ax = plt.subplot(111)
    ax.scatter(x,y,linewidth=1.5,s=size,facecolors='#0571b0',marker='o',alpha=0.5,label='A label')
    ax.scatter(x,z,linewidth=1.5,s=size,facecolors='#92c5de',marker='o',alpha=0.5,label='Another label')
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc='upper right',scatterpoints=1,fontsize=8)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you! That works. I knew I was doing something stupid. I have a further question - in your solution, the edits I make to the legend (e.g. fontsize) only appear in all but the last figure instance. The last figure instance doesn't get these edits - do you know why this is? How can I make sure that all the legends are identical?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. When I run the above, both legends are the same. Also when I change the fontsize, it will affect both legends equally.